# Unable to perform click operation on certain Elements, iOS 10 Automation with Appium 1.6.3

Tags: automation, appium, ios10

We are working on automation of a iOS application and are facing some major issues. Below is the summary of the environment setup and the issues faced with the solutions tried so far.

Environment setup done:
• As per client requirement, we had to work with iOS 10 and XCode 8. For fulfilling the requirement we had to upgrade our current Mac OS from 10.11 to 10.12.2.
• To work with iOS 10, we had to upgrade Appium from 1.5.3 to the latest version, 1.6.3.

Problems Faced: 
• In iOS 10, things have been moved from the original UIAutomation to XCUITest.
• The current application seems to be built on the old UIAutomation, the UI elements aren’t getting recognized by the new accessibility inspector.

Solutions Tried:
• We’ve tried performing click operations using x,y coordinates, but with no luck.
• We also tried writing relative xpaths, by getting the entire application hierarchy, but we’re still facing issues.

Appreciate a response from iOS automation experts, if any such challenges were faced and solutions that worked.

Answer (score -2):

If you inspect elements using Appium Inspector and choosen button on lets say Login screen has value for name property 'name=Login' or 'name=accessibility.login.button' you should be able to find element:

> _driver.FindElementByAccessibilityId("Login");

using FindElementByAccessibilityID("text value of name property") work always for element which has unique value of 'name=text value' for inspected element

When value for 'name=' is empty in inspector, you need to request in your dev team to add Accessibility Id tags to elements which allows you to interact with them.

If developers said they don't want to do that because its not in thier responsibilities (in modern agile dev teams everybody should care and work toward better quality of the product..) you need to go through product owner and conviced him that adding those acccessibility tags is bussiness case because it allows you to write automated tests which are making mobile regression shorter, faster and more stable than manual one - and at the end it allows to faster and safer releases of the app to production.